# SSMS status bar color bug

Tags: sql-server, user-interface, database-connection, ssms, ssms-2012

I tried to change the color of my status bar in ssms 2012 depending on the connection to registered servers. I registered the servers, checked "Use custom color:" in the connection properties and chose a color.

Now when I open a new query editor window, the color changes for something about half a second but then switches back to the default Khaki. Has anyone encountered the same problem?
Additional information:

- I had installed the trial version of SSMS Tools and uninstalled it after the trial period.
- I now use the tools: ApexSQL Complete, Refactor and Search.
- I use ssms via runas with another user and windows authentification for the connection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the new version of ApexSQL complete this error is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because ApexSQL Complete or another of they tool. It just happen to me, I installed Complete and Refactor and the Color for all my connections is rolled back to the default color.

Comment: Because of your message I uninstalled ApexSQL Complete, now the status bar color works like intended.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work reliably you need to set it in two different places in SSMS.

1. Connect button > Options > Connection Properties > “Use custom color” for that instance.
2. For the same instance, under Registered Servers: Properties > Connection Properties > “Use custom color” and then set the same color.

Source: https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/using-custom-connection-colors-in-ssms/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed now. I've setup a registered server with a custom color. When I log in thru a link on my desktop then the color kicks in. I'm on SSMS 14.0.17230.